# Using non repeating random number (in C)

Tags: c, random, srand

I have been given the assignment to create a non-repeating number generator, which generates 7 numbers. I have used the rand function. But not sure how to make sure the numbers are not repetitive. Thanks for the help

```
    int i, n;
    time_t t;
    n = 7;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
    printf("%d\t", rand() % 35);}
```

Comment: Fill an array with numbers 1-N, randomly shuffle the array, take first 7 numbers from array. To shuffle: for i in 1 to N, swap element i and element randomly chosen from range i..N.  Or do a web search: this is a super frequently asked question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all your previously created random number to an array and next time onward you have to compare the array value with newly created random number whether it has been already created or not. See below code and try yourself.

```
int i, n;
time_t t;
n = 7;
int randval[n]
int rval = 0;
int j = 0;
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
int found = 0;
for( i = 0 ; i < n ; ) {
  rval = rand();
  j = 0;
  found = 0;
  while(j++ < i ){
     if(rand[j] == rval){
       found = 1;
       break;
     }
  }
  if(!found){      
     randval[i] = rval;
     i++;
     printf("%d\t", rval % 35);
   }
}
```